# Add folder with exe file into newly created R package

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to create new package with some functions. I added folder called handyApps into root directory where are folders like data, man, R. Into that handyApps folder I added simple c# application with all it's files and folders such as bin, obj, Properties, ...

Then I implemented very simple logic where I'm calling this app using shell command. Once I finished "Build and Reload" process in RStudio I also built Source Package.

After all these processes I noticed there is no folder handyApps in "c:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\library\newPackageName".

Is there anything I missed during package building process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put non-standard directories into the `inst` directory in your package.  They'll be moved up a level when your package is installed.

In your case, that means putting the C# stuff into `inst/handyApps`.